# Having 2 WHERE Query's in a c# program

Tags: c#, sql

Hi i have this Query where it has to look at to different rows befor it can retrive the information and when I do this search

```
"SELECT * FROM houses WHERE Sold = No AND WHERE Type = A"
```

I get this error message

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Sold = No AND WHERE Type = A'."

Comment: You could've looked at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189499(v=SQL.105).aspx) for some [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188047.aspx). :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM houses WHERE Sold = No AND Type = A
```

You do not need to repeat the 'where' part, but just use `AND` / `OR`

Comment: This answer is ages old, but won't this also be a syntax error? Shouldn't `No` and `A` be in single quotes, because they are strings?

Comment: Quite probably, it was purely replicating the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use one WHERE in a SQL query

In your case you would do `WHERE Sold = No AND WHERE Type = A`

To make your `WHERE` more complex you can use the `AND` or `OR` operators and `()` brackets

For instance:

```
WHERE
col = something
AND
(
col1 = somethingElse
OR
col2 = somethingDifferent
)
```